# A better solution for a card game

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

So here's the task: you input an amount of cards with numbers from 1 to N. Then you input all of these numbers except one.
Your program should print the lost card number.
Here's my code:

```
n = int(input())
lst = []

for i in range(n - 1):
    lst.append(int(input()))

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if not i in lst:
        print(i)
```

But I need to do it without using lists. How is it possible?

Comment: The sum of all numbers is n*(n+1)/2. The sum of the numbers excluding one of them is sum(lst). How do you find the missing number..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set.difference` :

```
set(range(1, n + 1)).difference(lst)
```

Comment: If @Nofake isn't allowed to use lists, I highly doubt he or she is allowed to use sets.

Answer (score 1):

Keep taking the numbers and add them.

```
a = 0
a = a+newNumber
```

Then when you are done taking inputs. While you take inputs next time,
Start subtracting:

```
a = a-newNumber
```

The `a` at the end is the number which you did not take input next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
n = 12

s = {x for x in range(n)}
print(s)

pick = random.sample(s,1 ).pop(0)
print(pick)

s.remove(pick)

print(s)
```

Outputs:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
10
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach does not use any lists. It assumes you can use the `ast` module:

```
import ast

cards_1 = input("Enter your cards: ")
cards_2 = input("Enter the list again, with one missing: ")

total_cards_1 = ast.literal_eval(cards_1.replace(" ", "+"))
total_cards_2 = ast.literal_eval(cards_2.replace(" ", "+"))

print("{} is missing".format(total_cards_1 - total_cards_2))
```

Giving you the following possible output:

```
Enter your cards: 1 3 7 12
Enter the list again, with one missing: 12 3 1
7 is missing
```

If you cannot use `ast`, then the dangerous alternative is to use `eval()` as follows:

```
cards_1 = input("Enter your cards: ")
cards_2 = input("Enter the list again, with one missing: ")

total_cards_1 = eval(cards_1.replace(" ", "+"))
total_cards_2 = eval(cards_2.replace(" ", "+"))

print("{} is missing".format(total_cards_1 - total_cards_2))
```

`eval()` should though be avoided whenever possible.